# qlikview variable divided by count of a field where monthdatefield is last two months

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Ok so i have a variable `eIncorrect` and two fields `Total` and `CreatedMonthDate`

I want to create an expression which is the incorrect amount divided by the count of the total within the last two months.

I have tried this (might as well be pseudo):

```
=$(eIncorrect)/Count([Total]) where ([CreatedMonthDate] -2)
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use set analysis. Try something like this:

```
$(eIncorrect) / count({$<CreatedMonthDate={">=$(=max(CreatedMonthDate)-2)"}>}Total)
```

Comment: Of course it does, sorry! amended now to include the $ expansion that is required to operate an expression within the set analysis

Comment: The cause of the issue was the "Last two months" was hard coded into a variable (eIncorrect) by using - 62 days!

Comment: you can still reference a variable inside your set analysis `count({$<CreatedMonthDate={$(variablename)}>}Total)`

Comment: I know, the variable its self was incorrect by having a date limit inside of it